# Jackson deserialize based on type

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Lets say I have JSON of the following format:

```
{
    "type" : "Foo"
    "data" : {
        "object" : {
            "id" : "1"
            "fizz" : "bizz"
            ...
        },
        "metadata" : {
            ...
        },
        "owner" : {
            "name" : "John"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid custom deserializer and attempting to deserialize the above JSON (called Wrapper.java) into Java POJOs. The "type" field dictates the "object" deserialization ie. type = foo means the deserialize the "object" field using the Foo.java. (if type = Bar, use Bar.java to deserialize the object field). Metadata/owner will always deserialize the same way using a simple Jackson annotated Java class for each. Is there a way to accomplish this using annotations? If not, how can this be done using a custom deserializer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Annotations-only approach

Alternatively to the [custom deserializer approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123725/1426227), you can have the following for an annotations-only solution (similar to the one described in [Spunc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123978/1426227), but using `type` as an [external property](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)):

```java
public abstract class AbstractData {

    private Owner owner;

    private Metadata metadata;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public static final class FooData extends AbstractData {

    private Foo object;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public static final class BarData extends AbstractData {

    private Bar object;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Wrapper {

    private String type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = { 
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FooData.class, name = "Foo"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BarData.class, name = "Bar") 
    })
    private AbstractData data;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

In this approach, [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) is set to use `type` as an [external property](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY) to determine the right class to map the `data` property.

The JSON document can be deserialized as following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
```

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that BarData and FooData now are tied to this very specific AbstractData class. Imagine that FooData and BarData are to be used in a totally different part of the codebase that doesnt care at all how it was constructed (from JSON).

Comment: Slightly misread your code, looks like this approach could definitely work. The remaining pain point for me is that each type of object (Foo, Bar) will now need a corresponding FooData and BarData wrapper class and will lead to 2x classes being created for each type of type "object" being parsed. Any way to use typed generics or similar to get around that?

Comment: @JohnBaum Generics would do. However, as far as I know, you would need to define a `JavaType` or `TypeReference` when deserializing or handle it in a custom deserializer. My advice: don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123978/715660) only needs one superclass and only one class for each type of object. Generics would be overkill.

Comment: How to stop the type info showing the root dynamically , knowing i have this defined `@Generated("com.robohorse.robopojogenerator")
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "data")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "status", "numberOfUnits", "cost", "balance", "recipient", "dataCreated"})
@JsonSerialize(using = JacksonCustomMessageSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = JacksonCustomMessageDeserializer.class)`

Comment: @cassiomolin I tried this solution for my code, the Jackson was successfully able to convert the AbstractData to one of the type, but somehow the value of `type` was null

Comment: will it work for json which is not serialized by this serializer?

Answer (score 19):

### Custom deserializer approach

You could use a custom deserializer that checks the `type` property to parse the `object` property into the most suitable class.

First define an interface that will be implemented by `Foo` and `Bar` classes:

```java
public interface Model {

}
```

```java
public class Foo implements Model {

    // Fields, getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Bar implements Model {

    // Fields, getters and setters
}
```

Then define your `Wrapper` and `Data` classes:

```java
public class Wrapper {

    private String type;

    private Data data;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Data {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ModelDeserializer.class)
    private Model object;

    private Metadata metadata;

    private Owner owner;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The `object` field is annotated with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html), indicating the deserializer that will be used for the `object` property.

The deserializer is defined as following:

```java
public class ModelDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Model> {

    @Override
    public Model deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonMappingException {

        // Get reference to ObjectCodec
        ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();

        // Parse "object" node into Jackson's tree model
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);

        // Get value of the "type" property
        String type = ((Wrapper) jp.getParsingContext().getParent()
            .getCurrentValue()).getType();

        // Check the "type" property and map "object" to the suitable class
        switch (type) {

            case "Foo":
                return codec.treeToValue(node, Foo.class);

            case "Bar":
                return codec.treeToValue(node, Bar.class);

            default:
                throw new JsonMappingException(jp, 
                    "Invalid value for the \"type\" property");
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON document can be deserialized as following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
```

Alternatively to this custom deserializer, consider an [annotations-only approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124343/1426227).

Comment: Note that I had to annotate the `Foo` and `Bar` classes with the `@JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDeserializer.None.class)`. Otherwise, I ended up in an infinite loop. Note also that I used the newer Java `record` syntax. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921263/3757139

Answer (score 16):

All this can be done by means of annotations.

Create an abstract superclass with the common fields like "metadata" and "owner" and their getters/setters. This class needs to be annotated with [@JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html). It should look like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
```

With the parameter `property = "type"` you specify that the class identifier will be serialized under the field *type* in your JSON document.

The value of the class identifier can be specified with `use`. `Id.CLASS` uses the fully-qualified Java class name. You can also use `Id.MINIMAL_CLASS` which is an abbreviated Java class name. To have your own identifier, use `Id.NAME`. In this case, you need to declare the subtypes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "Foo"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "Bar")
})
```

Implement your classes Foo and Bar by extending from the abstract superclass.

Jackson's ObjectMapper will use the additional field "type" of the JSON document for serialization and deserialization. E. g. when you deserialise a JSON string into a super class reference, it will be of the appropriate subclass:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
AbstractBase x = om.readValue(json, AbstractBase.class);
// x will be instanceof Foo or Bar
```

**Complete code example** (I used public fields as shortcut to not need to write getters/setters):

```
package test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "Foo"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "Bar")
})
public abstract class AbstractBase {

    public MetaData metaData;
    public Owner owner;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "metaData=" + metaData + "; owner=" + owner;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Common fields
        Owner owner = new Owner();
        owner.name = "Richard";
        MetaData metaData = new MetaData();
        metaData.data = "Some data";

        // Foo
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.owner = owner;
        foo.metaData = metaData;
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
        customObject.id = 20l;
        customObject.fizz = "Example";
        Data data = new Data();
        data.object = customObject;
        foo.data = data;
        System.out.println("Foo: " + foo);

        // Bar
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.owner = owner;
        bar.metaData = metaData;
        bar.data = "A String in Bar";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        // Test Foo:
        String foojson = om.writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(foojson);
        AbstractBase fooDeserialised = om.readValue(foojson, AbstractBase.class);
        System.out.println(fooDeserialised);

        // Test Bar:
        String barjson = om.writeValueAsString(bar);
        System.out.println(barjson);
        AbstractBase barDeserialised = om.readValue(barjson, AbstractBase.class);
        System.out.println(barDeserialised);

    }

}

class Foo extends AbstractBase {
    public Data data;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[" + super.toString() + "; data=" + data + ']';
    }
}

class Bar extends AbstractBase {
    public String data;
    public String toString() {
        return "Bar[" + super.toString() + "; data=" + data + ']';
    }
}


class Data {
    public CustomObject object;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data[object=" + object + ']';
    }
}

class CustomObject {
    public long id;
    public String fizz;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomObject[id=" + id + "; fizz=" + fizz + ']';
    }
}

class MetaData {
    public String data;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MetaData[data=" + data + ']';
    }
}

class Owner {
    public String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Owner[name=" + name + ']';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it does not apply to the OP situation because the `type` is not defined under `object`. Hence `@JsonTypeInfo` won't work.

Comment: Already used in production (and unit tested there, of course). The property ```type``` will be introduced by Jackson. It won't work if you have a ```type``` field in the class itself.

Comment: If possible, I would be interested in seeing an example with `@JsonTypeInfo` that works with the situation mentioned by the OP.

Comment: `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)` could work. I will try it when I have the chance to.

Comment: I got your idea. For test purposes, I managed to create an example with `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)`. Let me show it.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124343/1426227) how I manage to do it with `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)`.

Comment: Looks like your code produces `{"type":"Foo","metaData":{"data":"Some data"},"owner":{"name":"Richard"},"data":{"object":{"id":20,"fizz":"Example"}}}`, which is a slightly different JSON from the one shown in the question. It could be fixed by moving `metaData` and `owner` members from `AbstractBase` to `Data` class.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is rather straight-forward. You probably have a super class that has properties for `metadata` and `owner`, so rather than making it truly generic, you could substitute T for your super class. But basically, you will have to parse the name of the class from the actual JSON string, which in your example would look something like this:

```
int start = jsonString.indexOf("type");
int end = jsonString.indexOf("data");
Class actualClass = Class.forName(jsonString.substring(start + 4, end - 2)); // that of course, is approximate - based on how you format JSON
```

and overall code could be something like this:

```
public static <T> T deserialize(String xml, Object obj)
        throws JAXBException {

    T result = null;

    try {

        int start = jsonString.indexOf("type");
        int end = jsonString.indexOf("data");
        Class actualClass = Class.forName(jsonString.substring(start + 4, end - 2)); 

        JAXBContextFactory factory = JAXBContextFactory.getInstance();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = factory.getJaxBContext(actualClass);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        // this will create Java object
        try (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
            result = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        log.error(String
                .format("Exception while deserialising the object[JAXBException] %s\n\r%s",
                        e.getMessage()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Be aware: this could leak to potential vulnerability: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/94.html