# Jackson - Read different object one by one from file

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a file like this:

```
[{
    "messageType": "TYPE_1",
    "someData": "Data"
},
{
    "messageType": "TYPE_2",
    "dataVersion": 2
}]
```

As you can see there is a file which contains different types of JSON objects. I also have an ObjectMapper which is able to parse the both types. I have to read the JSon objects one by one (because this file can be pretty huge) and to get the right Object (Type1Obj or Type2Obj) for each of them.

My question is how I could achieve with Jackson to read the JSon objects one by one from the file.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122782/jackson-deserialize-based-on-type using JsonSubTypes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphism in jackson annotations: @JsonTypeInfo usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798394/polymorphism-in-jackson-annotations-jsontypeinfo-usage)

Comment: As I said there is no problem anymore with the two different types. The question is that how I can read one by one the JSon Objects using Jackson. (I also edited the question to make it more clear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the array as a generic Jackson JSON object similar to

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
```

then traverse all the children of the array using

```
rootNode#elements()
```

and parse every one of the `JsonNode` children into the respective type using a check of `messageType` similar to

```
if ("TYPE_1".equals(childNode.get("messageType")) {
    Type1Class type1 = objectMapper.treeToValue(childNode, Type1Class.class);
} else // ...
```